# Deserializing Collections with protobuf-net

Tags: protobuf-net

During my switch from BinaryFormatter to protobuf-net,
I observed a difference when serializing collections.

In the code sample below, Deserialize (protobuf-net v2r470) returns
different results if an array is instantiated within
the class (street1) than outside (street2).

Is it not allowed to serialize collections instatiated within a class declaration?

```
[ProtoContract]
public class City
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string[] streets1;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string[] streets2 = new string[2];
}

City city = new City();

// Instantiate and populate streets1
city.streets1 = new string[2];
city.streets1[0] = "streetA";
city.streets1[1] = "streetB";

// Populate streets2. Already instantiated
city.streets2[0] = "streetA";
city.streets2[1] = "streetB";

// Serializing
using (var file = File.Create("city.bin"))
{
    Serializer.Serialize(file, city);
}

// Deserializing
using (var file = File.OpenRead("city.bin"))
{
    City  getCity = Serializer.Deserialize<City>(file);
}
```

Deserialize loads the following in getCity:

getCity.streets1: "streetA", "streetB"     (as expected)

getCity.streets2: null, null, "streetA", "streetB"  <--------- Why the null's ?

There are as many null's returned as there are items in the collection.

Answer (score 3):

It is, but the problem is that protobuf-net assumes (due to the concatenatable nature of the protobuf format) that it should **extend** (append to) lists/arrays, and your field-initializer is starting it at length 2.

There are at least 3 fixes here:

- you can add SkipConstructor=true to the ProtoContract, which will mean it doesn't run the field initializer
- there is a "replace lists" syntax on ProtoMember which tells it to replace rather than append (I can't remember the actual option, but it is there)
- you can add a before-deserialization callback to clear the field between the constructor and the deserialization

Comment: Thanks!  [ProtoContract(SkipConstructor=true)] works fine as well as [ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true)] for each collection field. Happy again!